# Criar array a partir de outro array json no php

Tags: php, json, array

Pessoal, tenho os seguinte array vindo de uma url a qual estou pegando via file_get_contents

```
$urlHistorical      = 'https://mfinance.com.br/api/v1/stocks/historicals/IBOV?months=3';
                                $dadosHistorical    = file_get_contents($urlHistorical);
                                $data_historical    = json_decode($dadosHistorical);
                                $historical         = $data_historical->historicals;
```

Aqui o retorno já filtrado no **historicals**

```
array (size=59)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'close' => float 103515.16
      public 'date' => string '2020-11-09T00:00:00Z' (length=20)
      public 'high' => float 105146.56
      public 'low' => float 100953.95
      public 'open' => float 100953.95
      public 'volume' => int 0
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'close' => float 105066.96
      public 'date' => string '2020-11-10T00:00:00Z' (length=20)
      public 'high' => float 105758.29
      public 'low' => float 103452.64
      public 'open' => float 103516.37
      public 'volume' => int 0
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'close' => float 104808.83
      public 'date' => string '2020-11-11T00:00:00Z' (length=20)
      public 'high' => float 105462.33
      public 'low' => float 104143.47
      public 'open' => float 105066.96
      public 'volume' => int 0
```

Estou precisando transforma o retorno acima nisto para montagem de uma gráfico, alguém consegue me dar um help como fazer isto no php? Obrigado

Os valores que vou usar serão em x: 'date', em y: [high, low, open, close]

```
data: [{
                    x: new Date(1538778600000),
                    y: [6629.81, 6650.5, 6623.04, 6633.33]
                },
                {
                    x: new Date(1538780400000),
                    y: [6632.01, 6643.59, 6620, 6630.11]
                },
                {
                    x: new Date(1538782200000),
                    y: [6630.71, 6648.95, 6623.34, 6635.65]
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é desta forma que precisas, mas espero que sirva de degrau em seu projeto.

```
<?php  

    $urlHistorical = 'http://mfinance.com.br/api/v1/stocks/historicals/IBOV?months=3'; // url exemplo...
    
    // ilustração dos dados recebidos da API (em JSON codificado)
    $dadosHistorical = '{"historicals":[{"close":103515.16,"date":"2020-11-09T00:00:00Z","high":105146.56,"low":100953.95,"open":100953.95,"volume":0},{"close":105066.96,"date":"2020-11-10T00:00:00Z","high":105758.29,"low":103452.64,"open":103516.37,"volume":0},{"close":104808.83,"date":"2020-11-11T00:00:00Z","high":105462.33,"low":104143.47,"open":105066.96,"volume":0},{"close":102507.01,"date":"2020-11-12T00:00:00Z","high":105018.66,"low":102033.75,"open":104810.06,"volume":0},{"close":104723,"date":"2020-11-13T00:00:00Z","high":104725.79,"low":102508.77,"open":102508.77,"volume":0},{"close":106429.92,"date":"2020-11-16T00:00:00Z","high":106518.16,"low":104728.51,"open":104728.51,"volume":0},{"close":107248.63,"date":"2020-11-17T00:00:00Z","high":107810.31,"low":105846.62,"open":106430.04,"volume":0},{"close":106119.09,"date":"2020-11-18T00:00:00Z","high":107467.25,"low":106043.35,"open":107245.54,"volume":0},{"close":106669.9,"date":"2020-11-19T00:00:00Z","high":106972.88,"low":105545.37,"open":106117.26,"volume":0},{"close":106042.48,"date":"2020-11-20T00:00:00Z","high":106763.96,"low":105680.28,"open":106669.9,"volume":0},{"close":107378.92,"date":"2020-11-23T00:00:00Z","high":107495.35,"low":106050.48,"open":106050.48,"volume":0},{"close":109786.3,"date":"2020-11-24T00:00:00Z","high":109956.18,"low":107360.58,"open":107377.95,"volume":0},{"close":110132.53,"date":"2020-11-25T00:00:00Z","high":110595.81,"low":109315.21,"open":109786.37,"volume":0},{"close":110227.09,"date":"2020-11-26T00:00:00Z","high":110244.5,"low":109418.33,"open":110132.53,"volume":0},{"close":110575.47,"date":"2020-11-27T00:00:00Z","high":111603.41,"low":110161.1,"open":110228.62,"volume":0},{"close":108893.32,"date":"2020-11-30T00:00:00Z","high":110933.68,"low":108829.15,"open":110598.01,"volume":0},{"close":111399.91,"date":"2020-12-01T00:00:00Z","high":111839.86,"low":108897.29,"open":108897.29,"volume":0},{"close":111878.53,"date":"2020-12-02T00:00:00Z","high":112315.42,"low":110579.16,"open":111401.76,"volume":0},{"close":112291.59,"date":"2020-12-03T00:00:00Z","high":113377.33,"low":111873.88,"open":111873.88,"volume":0},{"close":113750.22,"date":"2020-12-04T00:00:00Z","high":113863.73,"low":112293.76,"open":112293.77,"volume":0},{"close":113589.77,"date":"2020-12-07T00:00:00Z","high":114531.04,"low":112629.18,"open":113750.5,"volume":0},{"close":113793.06,"date":"2020-12-08T00:00:00Z","high":114381.14,"low":112820.31,"open":113589.77,"volume":0},{"close":113001.16,"date":"2020-12-09T00:00:00Z","high":114020.4,"low":112566.73,"open":113798.53,"volume":0},{"close":115128.63,"date":"2020-12-10T00:00:00Z","high":115261.71,"low":112731.76,"open":113002.26,"volume":0},{"close":115128,"date":"2020-12-11T00:00:00Z","high":115526.57,"low":113949.39,"open":115127.74,"volume":0},{"close":114611.12,"date":"2020-12-14T00:00:00Z","high":115740.1,"low":114431,"open":115136.91,"volume":0},{"close":116148.63,"date":"2020-12-15T00:00:00Z","high":116389.82,"low":114613.42,"open":114613.42,"volume":0},{"close":117857.35,"date":"2020-12-16T00:00:00Z","high":118178.44,"low":115495.75,"open":116148.97,"volume":0},{"close":118400.57,"date":"2020-12-17T00:00:00Z","high":119027.05,"low":117856.26,"open":117863.58,"volume":0},{"close":118023.67,"date":"2020-12-18T00:00:00Z","high":119370.48,"low":117638.24,"open":118395.23,"volume":0},{"close":115822.57,"date":"2020-12-21T00:00:00Z","high":118020.94,"low":114730.05,"open":118020.94,"volume":0},{"close":116636.18,"date":"2020-12-22T00:00:00Z","high":116902.54,"low":115648.34,"open":115824.66,"volume":0},{"close":117806.85,"date":"2020-12-23T00:00:00Z","high":118311.44,"low":116636.18,"open":116636.18,"volume":0},{"close":119123.7,"date":"2020-12-28T00:00:00Z","high":119212.79,"low":117804.95,"open":117805.56,"volume":0},{"close":119409.15,"date":"2020-12-29T00:00:00Z","high":119860.91,"low":118750.1,"open":119130.06,"volume":0},{"close":119017.24,"date":"2020-12-30T00:00:00Z","high":120149.85,"low":118919.43,"open":119409.85,"volume":0},{"close":118854.71,"date":"2021-01-04T00:00:00Z","high":120353.81,"low":118061.77,"open":119024.29,"volume":0},{"close":119376.21,"date":"2021-01-05T00:00:00Z","high":119790.06,"low":116756.08,"open":118834.88,"volume":0},{"close":119100.08,"date":"2021-01-06T00:00:00Z","high":120924.32,"low":118916.94,"open":119376.91,"volume":0},{"close":122385.92,"date":"2021-01-07T00:00:00Z","high":122696.64,"low":119100.76,"open":119103.07,"volume":0},{"close":125076.63,"date":"2021-01-08T00:00:00Z","high":125323.53,"low":122385.76,"open":122387.43,"volume":0},{"close":123255.13,"date":"2021-01-11T00:00:00Z","high":125075.18,"low":122505.58,"open":125075.18,"volume":0},{"close":123998,"date":"2021-01-12T00:00:00Z","high":124584.33,"low":123227.47,"open":123255.13,"volume":0},{"close":121933.08,"date":"2021-01-13T00:00:00Z","high":124031.68,"low":121015.6,"open":123996.2,"volume":0},{"close":123480.52,"date":"2021-01-14T00:00:00Z","high":123896.35,"low":121946.67,"open":121946.67,"volume":0},{"close":120348.8,"date":"2021-01-15T00:00:00Z","high":123471.59,"low":120185.13,"open":123471.59,"volume":0},{"close":121241.63,"date":"2021-01-18T00:00:00Z","high":122585.82,"low":120351.43,"open":120351.43,"volume":0},{"close":120636.39,"date":"2021-01-19T00:00:00Z","high":122120.24,"low":119257.03,"open":121249.84,"volume":0},{"close":119646.4,"date":"2021-01-20T00:00:00Z","high":121449.1,"low":118739.87,"open":120644.5,"volume":0},{"close":118328.99,"date":"2021-01-21T00:00:00Z","high":120242.86,"low":117785.13,"open":119628.41,"volume":0},{"close":117380.49,"date":"2021-01-22T00:00:00Z","high":118317.52,"low":116108.9,"open":118317.52,"volume":0},{"close":116464.06,"date":"2021-01-26T00:00:00Z","high":119167.14,"low":116109.1,"open":117380.89,"volume":0},{"close":115882.3,"date":"2021-01-27T00:00:00Z","high":117839.79,"low":114886.51,"open":116463.45,"volume":0},{"close":118883.25,"date":"2021-01-28T00:00:00Z","high":119355.23,"low":115733.6,"open":115882.3,"volume":0},{"close":115067.55,"date":"2021-01-29T00:00:00Z","high":118879.9,"low":114973,"open":118879.9,"volume":0},{"close":117517.57,"date":"2021-02-01T00:00:00Z","high":117861.51,"low":115093.16,"open":115093.16,"volume":0},{"close":118233.81,"date":"2021-02-02T00:00:00Z","high":119805.18,"low":117519.17,"open":117520.36,"volume":0},{"close":119724.72,"date":"2021-02-03T00:00:00Z","high":120210.38,"low":118234.28,"open":118234.99,"volume":0},{"close":119260.82,"date":"2021-02-04T00:00:00Z","high":120559.98,"low":118917.65,"open":119727.75,"volume":0}],"symbol":"IBOV"}';

    $dataHistorical = json_decode($dadosHistorical, true); // decodifico o JSON como objeto..

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dataHistorical['historicals']); $i++) {
        $arrGraph['data'][] = array(
            'x' => $dataHistorical['historicals'][$i]['date'],
            'y' => array($dataHistorical['historicals'][$i]['high'],
                $dataHistorical['historicals'][$i]['low'],
                $dataHistorical['historicals'][$i]['open'],
                $dataHistorical['historicals'][$i]['close']
            )
        );
    }

    print_r(json_encode($arrGraph)); // resultado
```

Comment: Obrigado campeão, funcionou certinho, só precisei ajustar o item [open] que tem que ser o primeiro na montagem do gráfico. Eu cheguei a conseguir fazer, mais de uma forma que com certeza não seria a mais correta hehehe, a sua ficou bem melhor, obrigado

Comment: Disponha irmão, defina minha resposta como "aceita e funcional" fica abaixo dos Votos, ao lado da resposta. Assim para poder ajudar outras pessoas, pois sua pergunta fica como Solucionada e Resolvida. Quaisquer duvida estamos ai!!